# Change name of folder in subversion *without* a checkout

Tags: svn

So, there is a folder in a subversion repository which is incorrectly named. I have been tasked with renaming it. Unfortunately, the repository is very large which means it takes quite a bit of time to try to check things out. It's also continually giving me "connection reset by peer" messages.

Is there a way to simply send the commit instruction to the repository without a checkout? I don't need to have a working checkout locally.

(If it is relevant, the repository is hosted in Assembla)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, for your direct question: `svn move` allows giving URLs in a repository, to avoid the need for a working copy for this one operation. For example,

```
svn mv http://example.com/svn/repo/trunk/path/to/dir http://example.com/svn/repo/trunk/path/to/renameddir -m "renaming poorly named directory"
```

But really, repository size should have basically no impact on this task. You DON'T need to check out a full repository for this task. Probably you don't need to check out the full repository for MOST tasks, really, so you should read on! A concept called a *sparse working copy* allows you to check out only what you need for your task. Additionally, always only checkout the subtree you need from the repository.

For your immediate task, you can create a working copy containing only the folders in the directory immediately above the one that needs a rename. To continue the example, you would get this working copy like this:

```
svn co --depth immediates http://example.com/svn/repo/trunk/path/to MY_WORKING_COPY
```

Note, this will also pull in any files in the "to" directory outside of subdirectories, if there are any. If you want to avoid those, that's also possible:

```
svn co --depth empty http://example.com/svn/repo/trunk/path/to MY_WORKING_COPY
svn up --set-depth empty MY_WORKING_COPY/dir
```

Note, the TortoiseSVN client allows easy automation of the second method, if you need a bunch of files/subdirectories.

Search the web for "sparse working copy" and you'll find plenty more info.